# Executing a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, ontology

I have created a small ontology. It has only one class called `methods` and a datatype property `action_nb` (integer).

Then I created two individuals :

> AHP => action_nb = 20
>
> electre  => action_nb = 50

I want to execute a simple query . Select method where nb_action < 40 and the results should give me EL1.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY untitled-ontology-77 "http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:untitled-ontology-77="http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#action_nb -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-77;action_nb">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-77;methods"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#methods -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-77;methods"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#ahp -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-77;ahp">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-77;methods"/>
        <action_nb rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">20</action_nb>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#electre -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-77;electre">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-77;methods"/>
        <action_nb rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">50</action_nb>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.2) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

```html
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/so#>
SELECT ?methods
WHERE {
   ?inst rdf:type ex:methods .
   ?inst ex:action_nb ?value .
FILTER (?value < 40)
}
```

this is the code that I have been manipulating: but it gave me only an empty row when filtering with 40 & 2 rows when using 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding how to approach this is to understand how RDF triples are defined.  You've stated that `action_nb` is the property whose values are integers that you want to compare.  Therefore create your query using that property:

```
PREFIX untitled-ontology-77: <http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#>
SELECT ?inst
WHERE {
    ?inst untitled-ontology-77:action_nb ?value .
    FILTER (?value < 40)
}
```

...where the `FILTER` clause allows only values of `action_nb` that are less than 40.

If the property is used in other classes, and you want to make sure that only members of `methods` are found, then you will also need to query for instances of that class:

```
PREFIX untitled-ontology-77: <http://www.semanticweb.org/diabolico/ontologies/2016/3/untitled-ontology-77#>
SELECT ?inst
WHERE {
   ?inst rdf:type untitled-ontology-77:methods .
   ?inst untitled-ontology-77:action_nb ?value .
   FILTER (?value < 40)
}
```

I doubt you'll need `DISTINCT` in this case, and be aware that finding all distinct values is performed after the query, but is applied pairwise to all SELECTED values. I.e. it may not perform well with large result sets.  Therefore, use `DISTINCT` only when necessary.

Comment: thanks so much for your help sir .
how to define the prefix (?inst) ? and what URI should i put in it ? i'm looking for an answer but i only found documents talking about (foaf) .

Comment: The `?` denotes a variable, not a namespace.  `:` denotes a prefixed namespace, and I've added one for clarity.  Try Googling SPARQL for more information on the query language.

Comment: i'm sorry , i meant the prefix ( ex: ) i have so much work left to do (java) this is just a part of it cause this is my PFE project and there is not much time left ... just help with this and i'll be grateful

Comment: i think i fixed it now .. but the result is empty .. it shows nothing

Comment: You'd have to post some sample data for anyone to help more.

Comment: Thanks.  Note that the prefix for your defined resources is 'untitled-ontology-77:'.  Also, I had mistakenly selected a variable that was not in the `WHERE` cause.  See if the above gets you closer.